# Find subsequences of a string whose length is as large as 10,000

Tags: c++, string, permutation

I have a string whose size can be as large as "10,000". I have to count those SUBSEQUENCES which are divisible by 9.

SUBSEQUENCE: A subsequence is an arrangement in which the **order** of characters of given string is maintained. For ex: if given string is 10292 then some of its subsequences are 1, 102, 10, 19, 12, 12(12 is twice as 2 comes twice), 129, 029, 09, 092, etc. Some numbers which are not subsequences of given string are: 201(2 and 0 can't come before 1), 921, 0291, etc.

I have tried to generate all subsequences(powerset) of given string using bit shifting and checking each string if it is divisible by 9. But this works fine as long as length of string is <=10. After that, I don't get proper subsequences(some subsequences are displayed negative numbers).

Below is my code:

```
    scanf("%s", &str); //input string 

    int n=strlen(str); //find length of string

    //loop to generate subsequences
    for(i=1;i<(1<<n);++i){

        string subseq;

        for(j=0;j<n;++j){

            if(i&(1<<j)){

                subseq+=str[j]; // generate subsequence
            }
        }

        //convert generated subseq to int; number is 'long' tpye
        number=atol(subseq.c_str());printf("%ld\n", number); 

        //ignore 0 and check if number divisible by 9
        if(number!=0&&number%9==0)count++;
    }

        printf("%ld\n", count);
```

Comment: A fun fact that may or may not help you:  If a number is divisible by nine, the sum of its digits is also divisible by nine.

Comment: @Xavier: So do you recommend me to find sum of all digits and then check for divisibility?!

Comment: As large as "10,000" means as long as 6 characters or 10000 characters?

Comment: ON a 32 bit system, the largest integer that can by held in an int is 2,147,483,648. After that, it overflows and the values become negative. you need to use something that's not an int

Comment: My approach would be to keep it as a string, add a function that takes a string and adds up the individual digits to determine if the number in the string is divisible by 9, and then pass all possible subsequences, as strings, to that function. There's probably a better way of doing it, but that should work

Comment: @Ghost - Eventually, sure.  But when there are `2^10000` possible substrings, eventually comes to mean a really _really_ long time.  There's gotta be a way to optimize this a lot; I just can't think of anything...

Comment: @Ghost: I liked your idea. But as Xavier says it would take a long time

Comment: MAybe something with [GNU MultiPrecision](http://gmplib.org/) to keep them as (kind of) integers? It's homework so I don't know what your limitations are with regard to external libraries

Comment: @XavierHolt: Yeah, I somehow don't think they'd give out a homework problem with a computational intensity of 2^10000.  OP: Are you sure they will give you a 10000 digit string?

Comment: @Wug: :D! Its a codechef problem..!

Comment: Are all of the strings purely numeric, or will there be mixed alphanumeric strings?

Comment: http://www.codechef.com/AUG12/problems/LUKYDRIV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a number is divisible by nine if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by nine, you can get away with this problem with a `O(n)` recursive algorithm.

The idea is the following: at each step, split in two the subsequence and determine (recursively) how many sequences have the sum of its digits be `i % 9`, where `i` ranges from `0` to `8`. Then, you build up this very same table for the whole range by "merging" the two tables in `O(1)` in the following way. Let's say `L` is the table for the left split and `R` for the right one and you need to build the table `F` for the whole range.

Then you have:

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  F[i] = L[i] + R[i];
  for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    if (j <= i)
      F[i] += L[j] * R[i - j]
    else
      F[i] += L[j] * R[9 + i - j]
  }
}
```

The base case for a subsequence of only one digit `d` is obvious: just set `F[d % 9] = 1` and all the other entries to zero.

A full C++11 implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

typedef std::array<unsigned int, 9> table;

using std::tuple;
using std::string;

table count(string::iterator beg, string::iterator end)
{
    table F;
    std::fill(F.begin(), F.end(), 0);
    if (beg == end)
        return F;
    if (beg + 1 == end) {
        F[(*beg - '0') % 9] = 1;
        return F;
    }
    size_t distance = std::distance(beg, end);
    string::iterator mid = beg + (distance / 2);
    table L = count(beg, mid);
    table R = count(mid, end);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        F[i] = L[i] + R[i];
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (j <= i)
                F[i] += L[j] * R[i - j];
            else
                F[i] += L[j] * R[9 + i - j];
        }
    }
    return F;
}

table count(std::string s)
{
    return count(s.begin(), s.end());
}

int main(void)
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    cout << count("1234")[0] << endl;
    cout << count("12349")[0] << endl;
    cout << count("9999")[0] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `L` and `R` values in the inner loop be multiplied, not added?

Comment: @XavierHolt: yup, it's the cartesian product (unless in the first case, when we just want to collect the left and right subsequences). Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had an idea!

Since you only have to *count* the substrings, you don't care what they actually *are*.  So instead, you can just store counts of their possible sums.

Then, what if you had a function that could combine the count tables of two substring sets, and give you the counts of their combinations?

And since I know that was a horrible explanation, I'll give an example.  Say you're given the number:

```
2493
```

Split it in half and keep splitting until you get individual digits:

```
   2493
   /  \
 24    93
 /\    /\
2  4  9  3
```

What can `2` sum to?  Easy:  `2`.  And `4` can only sum to `4`.  You can build tables of how many substrings sum to each value (mod 9):

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2: 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
4: 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
9: 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3: 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Combining two tables is easy.  Add the first table, the second table, and every combination of the two mod 9 (for the first combination, this is equivalent to `2`, `4`, and `24`; for the second, `9`, `3`, and `93`):

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
24: 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
93: 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0
```

Then do it again:

```
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2493: 3 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 0
```

And there's your answer, sitting there in the `0` column:  `3`.  This corresponds to the substrings `243`, `2493`, and `9`.  You don't know that, though, 'cause you only stored counts - and fortunately, you don't care!

Once implemented, this'll give you `O(n)` performance - you'll just have to figure out exactly how to combine the tables in `O(1)`.  But hey - homework, right?  Good luck!

Comment: `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(1)` is `O(n)`: you have `n(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/n) < 2n`.

Comment: @akappa - Thanks - I knew my math was a little funky...  Too much coffee, I'd imagine.  Cheers!

Comment: @XavierHolt When You write Substring did you actually mean Subsequence as Subsequence are different from Subsequence

Comment: @XavierHolt How would u handle the case when there are 0's in the input string as 0189.

Comment: @Luv technically speaking, 0's are divisible by nine, but if you just want the digit sum == 9, then you subtract ((number of zeros)^2)-1 from your final answer

Answer (score 0):

If you use **int** then you shouldnt left shift it too much. If you do, you set the sign bit. Use **unsigned int**. Or dont left shift too much. You can rightshift once you done if you insist on **int**.

for the

```
printf("%ld\n", count);
```

printf could have problems at displaying long-int types. Did you try cout ?

Comment: Better yet, store each digit as its own `char`.  It'll take up a lot more space, but it'll make dealing with individual digits - which you're doing a lot - _way_ easier.

Comment: @tugrul: converted to unsigned int, unsigned long.. no effect

Comment: @Stalin: printf could have problems at displaying long-int types. Did you try cout ? I had the same problem too but i dont remember how i fixed that.

Comment: @tugrul: tried cout.. no effect. I think I must go with Ghost's idea. Keep the subsequences as strings, find sum of digits and check for divisibility by 9. Thnx! Any other ideas are also welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Here's  C++ code according to Akappa's algorithm. However this algorithm fails for numbers that contain one or more 0s i.e. in cases of "10292" and "0189" but gives correct answers for "1292" ans "189". Would appreciate it if anyone could debug this to give answers for all cases.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector>
#include<stack>
#include<sstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cctype>
#include<list>
#include<set>
#include<set>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
typedef vector<int> table;
table count(string::iterator beg, string::iterator end)
{

    table F(9);
    std::fill(F.begin(), F.end(), 0);
    if (beg == end)
        return F;

    if (beg + 1 == end) {
        F[(*beg - '0') % 9] = 1;
        return F;
    }

    size_t distance = std::distance(beg, end);
    string::iterator mid = beg + (distance / 2);
    table L = count(beg, mid);
    table R = count(mid, end);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        F[i] = L[i] + R[i];
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (j <= i)
                F[i] += L[j] * R[i - j];
            else
                F[i] += L[j] * R[9 + i - j];
        }
    }
    return F;
}

table count(std::string s)
{

    return count(s.begin(), s.end());
}

int main()
{


     cout << count("1234")[0] << endl;

    cout << count("12349")[0] << endl;

    cout << count("9999")[0] << endl;

    cout << count("1292")[0] << endl;cout << count("189")[0] << endl;
    cout << count("10292")[0] << endl;cout << count("0189")[0] << endl;
    system("pause");


   }
```